# Get key-value pairs from a file for a list of keys from another file

Tags: bash

The simplified version of my problem is that I need a bash script that retrieves the key-value pairs from `file2` which have a key defined in `file1`.

For example:

`file1` (contains keys)

```
a
d
f
```

`file2` (contains key-value paris)

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
f=5
g=6
```

Expected output:

```
a=1
d=4
f=5
```

What I've tried:

```bsh
cat file1 | xargs -I % grep "^%=" file2
```

This works well but the performance is poor when the files are big. (e.g. file1 has 12k lines, file2 has 20k lines)

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{keys[$1]; next} $1 in keys' file1 FS='=' file2
a=1
d=4
f=5
```

Comment: Works wonderfully and feels pretty much instantaneous for my 12k/20k files. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `join`, `bash` and `sort`:

```
join -t '=' <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Output:

```
a=1
d=4
f=5
```

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much what `grep -f` is made for:

```
$ grep -f file1 file2
a=1
d=4
f=5
```

This searches for the keys from `file1` anywhere in the lines in `file2`, though, not just before the `=`; that might not work for your real data.

Comment: Yeah, in this case I needed it to be at the start of the line and before the = sign. But thanks for this answer, this might still be useful in other cases / for other people. It's a very useful feature for grep.